# Generator Expression with Random Module

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I am trying to generate a dict with a random.randint()

```
O = range(1, 6)
R = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
d = dict(((o, r), random.randint(1, 5)) for o in O for r in R)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'randint'
```

Comment: How do you import `random`?

Comment: I used: import random statement. I am also using from gurobipy import *

Comment: Are you sure? This error looks a lot like you did `from random import random`

Comment: Don't use wildcard imports, they might mess up your namespace in a way that is hard to trace.

Comment: schwobase asked the right question. BTW, an irrelevant note: this is not a dict comprehension - it's a generator expression ;)

Comment: The error occurred because of another module that uses: from random import *

Comment: @Boubakr this is why you shouldn't use starred imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely importing `random` like:

```
from random import random
```

when you should do

```
import random
```

Then, `random.randint` is the function you are looking for.